# Pointer to "value struct x"

Tags: c++-cli

How do I dynamically allocate a value struct and get a pointer to it?

If I have:

```
value struct x
{
    String ^myString;
};
```

I can do this:

```
x vsInstance;
x *pvs = &vsInstance; // "Unmanaged pointer" to managed object
```

And I can do this:

```
x ^vsInstance = gcnew x;
```

But I can't do this:

```
x *pvs = new vsInstance
```

**I need a * pointer rather than a ^ because I am trying to hold this value struct inside an unmanaged class, and I need to dynamically allocate this object every time a class is created.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what I was trying to do was unnecessary, I used gcroot which solved my design problem. However, I found that I can get a native pointer from pin_ptr but that it would not work in this circumstance